# Program to Spoonerise words

Tags: code-golf, string, word-puzzle, natural-language

A spoonerisation is swapping the first letter/pronounceable syllable of two or more words.

**Example**: A lack of pies = A pack of lies. Bad salad = Sad ballad (ish) :)

Challenge: Write a program to spoonerise two words in the shortest characters possible.

Rules:

1. If the first letter is a consonant, you must include subsequent letters until you reach a vowel. (e.g. 'thanks' - the th gets removed and put on the front of the other word).
2. With words that start with vowels, do not remove anything from the start of the word.

Good luck :)

---

**UPDATE:** Multiple word spoonerisms are [not strictly applicable](http://www.fun-with-words.com/spoon_history.html), however from a programatic view we must cater for them so this is the rule: **Every word must change.** Example:

Weird Keen Monkey -> Meird Ween Konkey **OR** Keird Meen Wonkey **NOT** Meird **Keen** Wonkey

Also 'y' is treated as a **vowel** (just to simplify things a bit)

Comment: To clarify, does "big apple" become "ig bapple", and does "ant eater" remain the same?

Comment: indeed - unless you can think of a better rule in which case I will add it in there :)

Comment: A "better rule" might involve using a word list to find an "optimal" spoonerization, but that would be a different and more complex problem.

Comment: Indeed, and would not be so easily golfable as it relies on the quality of your source model / API

Comment: I can't think of a retter bule.

Comment: Does the input have to be on STDIN?

Comment: @recursive - sorry what is STDIN? I'm an obj-c programmer

Comment: Standard input a.k.a. console input.

Comment: in that case, yes

Comment: You don't have to verify that the word exists in a dictionary - just swap? So `program to` would become `togram pro ...`, `spoonerise words` => `woonerise spords`?

Comment: that's correct :)

Comment: it was purely a coding challenge, not that it has a practical application!

Comment: What shall 'no year solution' be transformed to? 'yo near solution'? Or "Why do you cheat" or "rhythm and soul".

Comment: @user unkown see updated answer

Comment: updated question?

Comment: yes sorry I'm so used to typing see updated answer :)

Comment: `a pack of lies` was 4 words too, just only 2 starting with a consonant. So I thought, according with the old rules, we have to change the first 2 words, which don't start with a vowel. Now you changed the rules completly. Why? That's not clarification of the rules, but changing them.

Comment: 3 of the current solutions fail with 'a pack of lies' and return 'la pack of ies' - I didn't test that, because I wouldn't have thought somebody is presenting a solution, which does not solve the given examples.

Comment: To be tested with "Stack Overflow Rocks Hard"...

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to downvote the question, which wasn't well prepared. So the answers were coming in, while the question wasn't cleared. Related discussion: [more discipline](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/397/373) Place to prepare challenges and to find and remove ambiguities, beside chat: [Sandbox mk II](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/336/373)

Comment: The original question says "spoonerise two words". That seemed clear, and downvoting answers (including mine) that followed that spec doesn't sit right with me. The updated question says "every word must change". How should "a" in "a pack of lies" or "I" in "I like my bike" change? Presumably, the intent is that every word that starts with a consonant should change? Sorry, but I think the original was clearer, even though the examples of spoonerisms weren't examples of input.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby <strike>(60)</strike> <strike>(61)</strike> <strike>(93)</strike> <strike>(80)</strike> <strike>(75)</strike> <strike>(71)</strike> (69 / 57)

Program changed to handle the new requirement of handling multiple words.

EDIT: Golfed down to <strike>80.</strike> <strike>75.</strike> <strike>71.</strike> 69.

```
w=[];gets.gsub(/(\S*?)([aeiouy]\S*)/i){w+=[$2,' ',$1]};$><<w.pop+w*''
```

If we're only spoonerizing words that start with a consonant, here's a solution in <strike>73.</strike> <strike>65. (I realized I can just use scan instead of gsub.)</strike> 57.

```
$><<gets.gsub(p=/\b[^aeiouy\s]+/i){($'+$`+$&).scan(p)[0]}
```

Old program (two words only):

```
p='(.*?)([aeiou].+)';puts gets.gsub(/#{p} #{p}/i,'\3\2 \1\4')
```

Comment: Sorry - didn't see your answer until I posted mine.

Comment: No problem. I figure it's the simplest approach with Ruby anyway. And I learned a couple more tricks from seeing yours ;)

Comment: `echo "I like brasilian football" | irb spo-2.rb 
p='(.*?)([aeiou].+)';puts gets.gsub(/#{p} #{p}/i,'\3\2 \1\4')
fI like brasilian ootball`

Comment: The original problem only asked for spoonerizing two words. I don't know when the spec changed, but I'll fix this later.

Comment: From the question log `A lack of pies` was part of the initial question - 2 words (lack, pies) is the number of words starting with a consonant, isn't it?

Comment: I think you're interpreting the post wrong. Those are examples of spoonerisms, but the "Challenge" is "Write a program to spoonerise two words in the shortest characters possible."

Comment: Also, "2 words" does not refer just to the number of words starting with a consonant (which is consistent with the actual definition of a spoonerism). See Alex's comment on the question where he confirms that "big apple" becomes "ig bapple."

Comment: `A lack of pies = A pack of lies` was a solution in accordance with the rules: skip words which start with vowels. But now I see, how all that makes sense too - you ignored the example with 4 words, because it wasn't two words, and I translated '2 words' to '2 words, starting with consonants'. Now the question is still ambiguous: Alex says 'every word must change' and presents 3 words with different consonants. `so we will survive` can be modified, according to the rules, but what to do with `we will survive`? I'm sorry for all that trouble, but don't feel guilty.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 81

```
f[(a,b),(c,d)]=unwords[c++b,a++d]
main=interact$f.map(break(`elem`"aeiou")).words
```

Comment: May I ask you, after seeing 3 solutions failing miserably for untrivial input, how you handle `I like brazilian football`? (3 words, starting with consonants, and one word, just being one character? What about 'Why do you cheat'? :)

Comment: y is treated as a vowel therefore dy who chou yeat - off the top of my head, but when I wrote the question I was only aiming for 2 words

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <strike>57</strike> 56

This only works for the original problem (with only two words).

```
$><<gets.sub(/#{r='([^aeiou]*)(.+)'} #{r}/i,'\3\2 \1\4')
```

Comment: Assuming the input is always valid, you can replace \w+ with .+ to save another character.

Comment: `echo "consonants are really evil" | irb spo-1.rb 
$><<gets.sub(/#{r='([^aeiou]*)(.+)'} #{r}/i,'\3\2 \1\4')
onsonants are really cevil`

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 43 (question v1), 91 <strike>79</strike> (question v2) [107 to handle numerals in the phrase]

**v1**

Run with `-p` option (counted as 3 chars).

```
$p='([^aeiou]*)(.+)';s/$p $p/$3$2 $1$4/i
```

Same technique as the Ruby answers.

Using `-p` saves 9 characters over bracketing the code with `$_=<>;` and `;print` for explicit IO.

**v2**

Run with `-lp` (counted as 4 chars).

```
push@a,$1while s/\b([^ aeiouy\d]+)(?=[aeiouy])/$n++/ei;unshift@a,pop@a;s/(\d+)/$a[$1]/g
```

Rotates all the consonant-starts of words one word forward.

*Updated:* Add vowel lookahead, so it handles "to the nth degree" more gracefully ("do te nth thegree", not "do te th nthegree").

*Numerals:* user unknown asked about handling "There is no winner in 2011", because of the numerals. Adding markers around the numbers my solution uses, it can handle that:

```
push@a,$1while s/\b([^ aeiouy\0\d]+)(?=[aeiouy])/"\0".$n++."\0"/ei;unshift@a,pop@a;s/\0(\d+)\0/$a[$1]/g
```

Small question, big discussion....

Comment: `echo "I like my bike" | perl5.10.1 -p spoon.pl
bI like my ike`

Comment: I'm of the opinion that numerals and doing special case handling for words like 'nth' are beyond the spec. We're already treating 'y' as a vowel in all cases (even in words like 'you'), so I don't see why you're starting to take pronunciation into account.

Comment: @migimaru: With 'nth', pronunciation wasn't my concern, but motion of the entire word.  Hard to tell, the way this question has progressed, what a solution should handle or not.  Anyhow, nicely done with the ruby solution.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 77

*Answers the original version of the question, "spoonerise two words"; a solution for the changed question may follow.*

Couldn't shrink this to compete with the Ruby answers, so fell back on my more-familiar Perl.

```
exit([:;3 1 2 0 4{[:,({.@I.@e.&'aeiouAEIOU'({.;' ';~}.)]);._2@,&' ')&.stdin''
```

- `,&' '` appends a space
- `(`...`);._2` splits on the last character (the space) and applies
  the parenthesized code to each element (i.e., each word)
- `{. @ I. @ e.&'aeiouAEIOU'` finds the index of the first vowel in that
  word
- `({.;' ';~}.)` splits the word into leading consonants (if any) and a
  tail, with a space at the end (each in a "box", so J doesn't pad them to matching lengths)
- `,` flattens the 2r x 3c matrix formed by the preceding into a
  6-element list
- `3 1 2 0 4{` takes all those elements but the trailing space, swapping the lead
  segments of the words
- `;` unboxes and concatenates the elements
- `(`...`)&.stdin''` does roughly the same as Perl's `-p`, reading stdin and echoing the result of "..." to stdout
- the explicit `exit` suppresses J's prompt for more input

Answer (score 0):

#### CSharp - 236

```
List<string> f(string w) {var t="aeiou".ToCharArray();var q=w.Split(' ').Where(c=>!t.Contains(c[0]));var i=q.Count()-1;return q.Select(c=>q.Select(x=>x.Substring(0,x.IndexOfAny(t))).ToList()[i--]+c.Substring(c.IndexOfAny(t))).ToList();}
```

Comment: Is this a program or a function?

Answer (score 0):

### Scala 244

```
val s=readLine
def f(a:String,b:String)=a.replaceAll("^[^aeiouy]+",b.replaceAll("[aeiouy].*",""))
val l=("((^| )[^aeiouyAEIOUY]+)([^ ]+)".r findAllIn s map(_.trim)).toList
println(s.replaceAll(l(0),f(l(0),l(1))).replaceAll(l(1),f(l(1),l(0))))
```

My code contains 4 `y` (one of them lowercase) to handle `why` and `rythm` in a useful manner.

---

#### Scala 248, updated for new challenge (change *all* consonantic words)

```
val w=readLine.split(" ")
val c=w.filter(_.matches("[^aeiouyAEIOUY].*"))
val l=c.size
var k=0
println((for(i<-0 to w.size-1)yield{if(w(i)==c(k%l)){k+=1
c(k-1).replaceAll("^[^aeiouy]+",c(k%l).replaceAll("[aeiouy].*",""))}else w(i)}).mkString(" "))
```

#### ungolfed, and test cases:

```
val samples = List ("bad salad", "I tell smooth", "Sentence with vowel in the end", "tain bruck is faboo")
def konsInit (s: String) = s.matches ("[^aeiouyAEIOUY].*")
def flipInit (a: String, b: String) = a.replaceAll ("^[^aeiouy]+", b.replaceAll ("[aeiouy].*", "")) 
def spoonize (sentence: String) {
  val words = sentence.split (" ")
  val kwords = words.filter (konsInit);
  val len = kwords.size
  var k = 0
  val spoonies = for (i <- 0 to words.size-1) yield {
    if (words (i) == kwords (k%len)) {
      k += 1
      flipInit (kwords (k-1), kwords (k%len)) 
    } else words (i) 
  }
  println (spoonies.mkString (" ")) 
}
samples.foreach (spoonize)
```

> sad balad
>   I smell tooth
>   wentence vith thowel in Se end

The last example can't be shown.

Comment: I'm not sure what we're considering correct behavior for all-consonant words, but "to the nth degree" => "tho nthe d tegree" seems sub-optimal.

Comment: Is 'nth' considered a regular word? Abbrevations without vowels, numbers, dates or sentence marks have not been discussed too - do you handle 'There is no winner in 2011'? My dictionary contains no word between nozzle and nuance. But meanwhile I recognized that all others interpret the  question different than me, and try to solve the `big apple` problem. I guess I will delete my post.

Comment: Foremost, I do not suggest you delete your post. You do seem to have been rather critical (as in offering critique, not necessarily negative) of others', so I thought you'd want the feedback. Nth is indeed a word (e.g., see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nth). My code does not handle digits, though it should be adaptable.

Comment: Yes, 'nth' is a special case, worth mentioning, but until today I would have said, that there isn't a word without vowel in the English language. My dictionary is 'Langenscheidt', by the way. I could try to rewrite my solution, but I'm already outside of the specs with acting wrong on 'big apple'. Now I slowly get enough of this. You can always find special cases, but this puzzle was nearly not prepared. From the question, I can't derive how my program should act on input like 'nth'.

Comment: nth is pronounced 'enth', so you could treat it like it starts with a vowel.